# update a row of a table using a second row stacked in a Json, Python and Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have the next table:

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | y |
| 2 | z | w |

And also the next json:

```
{'id' : 1, 'column1' : a, 'column2' : b}
```

I want to update the table row with id 1 (the id of the json), with the values in the json.
I am using python, and I interact with the data base using sql (PostgreSQL).
the result will be :

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 2 | z | w |

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix the format of the JSON by quoting the string values along with the quoted keys such as

`{'id' : 1, 'column1' : 'a', 'column2' : 'b'}`

Then you can prefer using `ast.literal_eval` safely evaluate a dictionary expression in order to get a parameter list to be used for the DML statement as

```
import ast
import pg8000
con = pg8000.connect(...)
cur = con.cursor()

Js="{'id' : 1, 'column1' : 'c', 'column2' : 'd'}"
data = ast.literal_eval(Js)

prm=[data['column1'],data['column2'],data['id']]

cur.execute("UPDATE tab SET column1=%s, column2=%s WHERE id=%s",prm)
con.commit()
```